# ACE.js code editor how to use beautify for HTML,CSS,JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, code-editor

**Problem:**

When I get a string of HTML in a text string and to insert/or set ACE.js editor value, and to use beautify to tidy/ indent the code, however it is not working, I was wondering if `ext-beautify.js` which is provided by ACE.js is supporting html,css,js beautifying? what am I doing wrong here?

```
var htmlString = "<div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12"><span>chrome</span></div></div>";

var editor = ace.edit("editor");
editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/html");
editor.session.setValue(htmlString);

var beautify = ace.require("ace/ext/beautify");
beautify.beautify(editor.session);
```

**Output on ACE.js editor**

```
<div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12"><span>chrome</span></div></div>
```

**But I need it to be**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <span>chrome</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestion or solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have also tried beautify extension of ace editor and it was not working for me as well, output was in single line only. I have gone through [JS Beautifier](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify) and it works perfectly fine. It has options to beautify JS, HTML and CSS. You can use HTML module to beautify your code in Ace Editor. I have attached the sample code below for same:

HTML:

```
<div id="editor"></div>
```

JS:

```
var htmlString = '<div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12"><span>chrome</span></div></div><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12"><span>mozilla</span></div></div>';
htmlString = html_beautify(htmlString);

var editor = ace.edit("editor");
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/html");
editor.session.setValue(htmlString);
```

Running [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c6v523ug/4/) link.